# How to split up modular javascript into different files

Tags: javascript, file, module

I have this javascript:

```
(function(sa){

  // initialize the application
  var init = function(){

    // creata new Core instance
    var core = new sa.Core();

    // create the helloWorld module
    var HelloModule = function(sandbox){

      // dom reference
      var container = null;

      // boot your module
      var init = function(){

        // create a reference to the module's html element
        container = document.getElementById(sandbox.instanceId);

        // say hello
        container.innerText = container.textContent = "Hello World!";
      };

      // shutdown your module
      var destroy = function(){

        // clean your container
        container.innerText = container.textContent = '';
      };

      // return public module API
      return {
        init: init,
        destroy: destroy
      }
    };

    // register the module
    core.register("helloWorld", HelloModule);

    // create element references
    var startButton = document.getElementById("start");
    var stopButton  = document.getElementById("stop");
    var logElement  = document.getElementById("log");

    // creat log method
    var log = function(msg){
      var li = document.createElement("li");
      li.innerText = li.textContent = msg;
      logElement.appendChild(li);
    };

    // bind start button
    startButton.onclick = function(){
      core.start("helloWorld", function(err){
        if(err) return log(err.message);
        log("started 'helloWorld' module");
      });
    };

    // bind stop button
    stopButton.onclick  = function(){
      core.stop("helloWorld", function(err){
        if(err) return log(err.message);
        log("stopped 'helloWorld' module");
      });
    };
  };

  // return public API
  window.app = {
    init: init
  };

})(window.scaleApp);
```

It is the HelloWorld example from [scaleApp](https://github.com/flosse/scaleApp/) (I am learning about coding in modules). I want to add my own module, and I'm wondering about splitting up my code into different files. I wanted to write my own module in a separate file, and have it get loaded into the core (i.e. `core.register("helloWorld", HelloModule);`), and then I need to be able to write the necessary functions (like `startButton.onclick`) which are in the app's `init` function. How can I expose the `init` function and the core in a separate javascript file?

Comment: Use a framework

Comment: is this what requirejs does?

Comment: Basically yes that's what requirejs does. But I recommend looking into using Vue.js with Webpack as a more professional approach, or just Webpack. Webpack bundles together all your scripts and dependencies into one single script file.

Comment: also, what if i want to keep going without a framework...what does the simplest structure look like?

Comment: is it frowned upon to leave all the js code in one file?

Comment: RequireJSBwill help you organize your code. Leaving all the code in one file will make it difficult to maintain.

Comment: thanks @user2182349 thats the distinction i was looking for